# how to debug Mocha when it continually opens new Debugggers

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, mocha.js

I keep having this issue where Mocha opens multiple debuggers when I run `mocha --inspect-brk`. Even though Chrome easily attaches its Node inspector to the first debugger process, it never attaches to the second process that Mocha starts up and Mocha just hangs forever.

How do I get Chrome to continue to attach inspectors to all the processes that Mocha starts up?

For example, I run `mocha --inspect-brk` and get the following output printed to my terminal:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/xxxx
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:43210/xxxx
```

While Chrome attaches easily to `127.0.0.1:9229` (which you can see in the logs above with `Debugger attached`), it does not attach to `127.0.0.1:43210`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when Mocha opens processes with debuggers that use ports which Chrome's Node inspector does not know about yet. In the example, `43210` is the port which Chrome isn't trying to attach debuggers to.

Here's how to solve this:

1. run `mocha --inspect-brk`
2. copy the host of websocket URL that never gets a debugger attached to it (in the given example, this would be `127.0.0.1:43210`)
3. open Chrome
4. go to `chrome://inspect/#devices` in Chrome
5. click `Open dedicated DevTools for Node`
6. open the `Connection` tab (next to the `Console` tab) in the new window that pops up
7. click `Add connection`
8. paste in the copied host name (from step 2) to Chrome for the new connection

Now Chrome will connect an inspector to the new process! If any other port numbers are used in subsequent processes that Chrome doesn't connect to, simply add those to Chrome's Node inspection connection list as well.